# ReactJS setState method: Time updates per second but 'greeting' won't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wondering about the fact that why is time getting updated every second but greeting updates only once when I run the code? I know this probably has something to do with the fact that React **updates only whats necessary.** Here's the code:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { date: new Date(), greeting: "Bonjour" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(timerID);
  }

  tick = () => { this.setState({ date: new Date(), greeting: "Hola" }); }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.greeting} {this.props.name}!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()} right now!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `greeting` text is hardcoded to `Hola`. So it is same for every update.

Comment: `"Bonjour"` -> `"Hola"` is one state transition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While every second the tick variable is set to a new Date, the greeting state variable is set to `Hola` everytime. So at 1second when first time `tick` is called `greetings` changes from `Bonjour` to `Hola` and every subsequent time, since its set to Hola, it re-rendered with the same value

Hence in your case greetings only updates once. In case you want it to also change, you can define a set of possible values and show them either in a loop or randomly

```js
const greet = ["Hola", "Hey", "Bonjour", "Hi" ];
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { date: new Date(), greeting: "Bonjour" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(timerID);
  }

  tick = () => { 
     const ridx = Math.floor(Math.random(greet.length)*(greet.length));
  this.setState({ date: new Date(), greeting: greet[ridx] });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.greeting} {this.props.name}!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()} right now!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

} 

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```